# Extract Key/value from file to another file in unix

Tags: bash, unix

Hello i have used this code to extract Key/Value from file to another file

```
BugReports: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=194
NeedsCompilation: no
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2014-03-02 12:40:42" > FichierTest


IFS=":" 
echo $(while read f1 f2
do 
   echo "$f1 ; $f2" 
done < FichierTest) > test.dsc
```

content of test.dsc:

```
BugReports ;  https //r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=194
NeedsCompilation ;  no
Repository ;  CRAN
Date/Publication ;  2014-03-02 12 40 42
```

I just want to change the first colon ":" to semi-colon ";" in each line

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use one-time matching with `sed`?

```
sed -e 's|:|;|' file
```

Output:

```
BugReports; https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=194
NeedsCompilation; no
Repository; CRAN
Date/Publication; 2014-03-02 12:40:42
```

Or if you really want to replace everything:

```
sed -e 's|:|;|g' file
```

Output:

```
BugReports; https;//r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=194
NeedsCompilation; no
Repository; CRAN
Date/Publication; 2014-03-02 12;40;42
```

Add spaces to replacement if needed.

By the way, the reason why your output gets spaces instead of colons in some parts is because `IFS` still has its effect on word splitting. You have to quote your command substitution on it to fix it:

```
IFS=":" 
echo "$(while read f1 f2
do 
   echo "$f1 ; $f2" 
done < FichierTest)"
```

Output:

```
BugReports ;  https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=194
NeedsCompilation ;  no
Repository ;  CRAN
Date/Publication ;  2014-03-02 12:40:42
```

And the proper way to do it actually is this:

```
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2; do 
   echo "$f1 ; $f2" 
done < FichierTest
```

Comment: Damn, you know too much about `bash`.

Comment: You might want to fix the wacky `echo $(echo...)` in the last `IFS` example.

Comment: @tripleee Added. I actually don't recommend it :) Better just use `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

The question was tagged with bash. In Bash you can do search & replace without sed or any subshells, just by [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
while read -d $'\n' -r line; do
    echo "${line/:/;}"
done <FichierTest >/tmp/test.dsc
```

If you wanted to replace all occurences of the colon and not just the first, you'd use `${line//:/;}`